# Data is not initialized from another class

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a function that returns weather data (not in an array). This function is initialized in the ViewModel. And as completion I use typealias. But when the data in the viewModel is received and I pass it to the View, nothing happens in fuction ab().
It is ViewModel Code:

```swift
protocol Alias { 
   typealias type = ([Convertible], Convertible) -> Void
   typealias DidFetchUserLocationCompletion = (Location) -> Void 
}

final class MainControllerViewModel: NSObject, Alias {
   var didFetchUserLocation: DidFetchUserLocationCompletion?
   var completion: type?
   private var weather = [Convertible]()
   private var weatherModel = [DailyForecast]()
   private var initWeather: WeatherOneDayInitializer!
   private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
      return dateFormatter
   }()

   func getLocation() {
      LocationManagerSaver.shared.fetchLocation { [weak self] (location, error) in
         guard let location = location else { return }
         self?.didFetchUserLocation?(location)
      }
   }
}
```

and it is View code:

```swift
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   fileprivate var weather = [Convertible]()
   fileprivate var mainViewModel = MainControllerViewModel()
   fileprivate var viewModel: MainControllerViewModel? {
      didSet {
         guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
         ab(viewM: viewModel)
      }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      viewModel = MainControllerViewModel()
      locationManager.delegate = self
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let nib = UINib(nibName: CollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, bundle: nil)
      collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
   }

   func ab(viewM: MainControllerViewModel) {
      viewM.completion = { item, one in
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(one.temperature)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `getLocation()`even called?

Comment: @Larme Of course, I see the result in the console, and if I write print (location.lat) in viewModel class I will see the result, but if i try same in view, nothing happens

Comment: "nothing happens in fuction ab()" - what is the expected outcome?

Comment: @koen 
print (one.temperature) does not print to the console

Comment: So is `print()` not executed, or is `one.temperature` nil?

Comment: @koen it seems yes, since the breakpoint does not work. 
I think there is no value, and the ab () function does not work in view. But I do not know why

Comment: So if `ab()` is not called, then in `guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }` your viewModel must be nil.

Comment: @koen yes, not called. I put an end to print ()

Comment: You only set `mainViewModel`, not `viewModel` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @koen oh yes this is my mistake but nothing has changed after I fixed it

Comment: Can you fix that in the question?

Comment: @koen Yes, look, please. I changed

Comment: I recommend that you step through your code and check every property to make sure they have the value you expect. And to follow up @Larme's comment, where are you calling `getLocation()`?

Comment: @koen thank you very much, everything works, the fact is that at the time the topic was created I tried didSet and willSet, when I fixed the initialization on mainView, I had willSet in the project, now I fixed it on didSet and everything works! I am very happy for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help.